# Display message success after docker-compose up is done

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I run many services in my docker-compse.yml. I'd like to display a message to let user know when docker-compose up is done?
I tried to echo message with command but my container exited with code 0

```
command: bash -c "echo Congratulation! You can use your containers now"
```

Is there anyway to let user know when docker-compose up is done?
Many thanks!

Comment: you can check container status
for example for 2 container:
docker ps -f name=api -f name=celery

Comment: This is not I mean. I just need to show message to user to let them know docker-compose up is done.

Comment: What do you mean by done? Do you mean that docker-compose has finished running it's start-up scripts, or do you mean that your stack is in a working state? For instance, an express server can be 'up' as far as docker is concerned, but still be a minute before it is capable of serving (in dev mode, for instance.)

Answer (score 3):

Anything you do in CMD will only be visible in the logs, and only per service, so you may as well just watch the logs which I assume is what you're trying to avoid. If you want it to work from the local command line you're going to need to wrap the `docker-compose up` command.

***THE following is NOT fully tested. This is for guidance only.*** I use the getContainerHealth and waitContainer scripts myself, so ***can*** vouch for them. I'm fairly sure I found them on this site, but can't remember where.

Assuming you're waiting for your services to be in a usable state, you could use something similar to this compose file:

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  serviceOne:
     // ... the usual stuff
    container_name: serviceOne
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 1s

  serviceTwo:
     // ... the usual stuff
    container_name: serviceTwo
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 1s
```

The commands in the test are the commands you use to define the service is up and running. More info here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck

You will probably want different health checks (or at least intervals, timeouts, start_periods, etc) for production and development.

then some bash script that you use instead of docker-compose up:

```
getContainerHealth () {
  docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health.Status }}" $1
}

waitContainer () {
  while STATUS=$(getContainerHealth $1); [ $STATUS != "\"healthy\"" ]; do
    if [ $STATUS = "\"unhealthy\"" ]; then
      echo "Failed!"
      exit -1
    fi
    printf .
    lf=$'\n'
    sleep 1
  done
  printf "$lf"
}

waitContainers () {
  waitContainer serviceOne
  waitContainer serviceTwo
  // ... for all services
}

docker-compose up
echo "In progress. Please wait"
waitContainers
echo "Done. Ready to roll."
```

Answer (score 1):

create a shell file echo.sh that contains
echo "Your message"

In Docker file add
CMD ["/dockerRepo/echo.sh"]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running something like the following directly in the Dockerfile itself ?

```
RUN echo -e "Your message"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|` and `while` loop

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  cmd:
    container_name: my-node-cmd-1
    image: node:16.10.0
    volumes:
      - .:/work
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        echo "----------------------------------------------"
        echo "To join to CMD, in separate console execute:"
        echo " "
        echo 'docker exec -it my-node-cmd-1 bash -c "cd /work; bash"'
        while true; do sleep 10000; done
```

Above working example gives access to node cmd in current directory - if you copy it to `docker-compose.yml` and run by `docker compose up` you should see

[image]

The `while` loop is infinite but sleep 10s on each iteration. If you remove line with this loop then container will `exit with code 0`

BONUS

You can get similar effect to above example by using `run` instead `up` on following script

```js
version: "3.9"

services:
  # run this container by: docker compose run cmd
  cmd:
    image: node:16.10.0
    volumes:
      - .:/work
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        echo "Hello World!"
        cd /work
        bash
```